# HTML/CSS - Issues between Firefox and Chrome, and IE

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a site for a friend, and the code I'm using is showing up differently in Firefox and Chrome - the way it is in Chrome is the way I want it to look, but Firefox is messing something up.
If anyone has any ideas how to get it to work in Firefox like it works in Chrome, I would really appreciate it.
Also, the Flash elements don't seem to be showing up in IE at all...
Any ideas?
Thanks!!

EDIT: I reinstalled Flash Player in IE and it seems to be working now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I problem I can see is the "v1" class style to "v.." of the div do not have the desired height rendered in FF.

Try this:

CSS:

```
div.vItem {
  height: 17px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="v1 vItem'...</div>
<div class="v2 vItem'...</div>
<div class="v3 vItem'...</div>
.
.
.
<div class="v10 vItem'...</div>
```

For the flash, I have no problem with the Flash on IE6 and IE8 though.

Comment: Looks like that worked... I may just add the height and width to each class manually, because I'm not really sure how to use two classes in one - can you elaborate. and show a bit more of the example? Do I need to do any more than <div class="v1 vItem'> on the top? Thanks!

Comment: You do not have to use 2 classes. What I did in my codes was to partition out the common style properties of the "v.." elements so that you do not have to repeat them in every class. You can learn more here: http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/qt/tipcssmulticlas.htm

Comment: OK, thanks a lot!!
Gonna look into that.
I really appreciate it!

Comment: No prob, that's what this site is for :) Glad I can help.

Answer (score 0):

strange things are happening on your site. You have an object in an object tag (flash) that is not allowed i think. This could be the problem why IE8 is not rendering the flash buttons.
Maybe you could replace al the `div`s with a list `ul` and `li` this is semantically better and will make styling of every button easier.

You should change the height of the `div`s or when replaced by the list, the height of the `li`s This will make them more compact as in chrome

Answer (score -1):

You might put your code to following quick trials to see if the problem is solved:

1: If your doc type is **strict**; try replacing it with below line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

2: Try adding Eric Meyer's Reset.css to your css file on top:

```
http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2008/01/15/resetting-again/
```

Hope that helps.